# Get drop down with kitty

Tags: i3, kitty

I used to use guake and I preferred the drop down style of it so is there a way to have this in kitty. So far i have tried [kitti3](https://github.com/LandingEllipse/kitti3) and added

```
exec_always --no-startup-id kitti3
bindsym $mod+n nop kitti3
```

*NOTE: I am using i3 gaps with python3.8*
when I tried executing this command manually the output is

```
$ nop kitti3
Can't open kitti3
```

Comment: It looks like i3 is unaware of the path to kitti3, so I'd try wrapping it into a variable (for the sake of brevity).  Something like `set $kitti3 /home/perseus/.local/bin/kitti3` and then replacing `kitti3` with `$kitti3` in the config above.

Comment: Also note that in `bindsym <smth> nop kitti3`, `nop` is not a shell command.  It is an instruction to i3 to not execute anything but output what goes after `nop` to logs.  Kitti3 listens to those logs and pops the terminal window once the message appears.

Answer (score 0):

What is the output of `which kitti3`? It seems like your system doesn't recognize `kitti3`

Comment: It is `/home/perseus/.local/bin/kitti3`